# How to access an Android color resource from JS in a NativeScript project?

Tags: android, colors, resources, nativescript

In my NativeScript project, I have a color defined in App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="notification">#00546A</color>
</resources>
```

Now I try to access the value of the defined color like this:

```
utils.ad.getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(
    android.R.color.notification, 
    null
)
```

But I always get:

> android.content.res.Resources&NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

I also tried:

```
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(
    utils.ad.getApplicationContext(), 
    android.R.color.notification
)
```

... but same result.

Does anybody have a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var app = require('tns-core-modules/application');
app.getNativeApplication().getResources().getIdentifier("color_name", "color", app.getNativeApplication().getPackageName());
```

Comment: To convert color ID to NativeScript Color object: `new Color(app.getNativeApplication().getResources().getColor(colorId));`